# Optimising table design or optimising the query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am trying to decide which one is better: to design a table that wastes a lot of space and has a simple query OR to write a very tight table but then the process of finding what I am looking for would be very processing intense.

The actual problem is this:

Imagine you have a very simple table. 1st column for the ID number the 2nd is a list of names and the 3rd is a list of names too. The 2nd column is a list of people who owe to the people in the 3rd column.

The search should do the following:

I search for a name in the 3rd column and see who owes this person in the 2nd column. A name or multiple names come up, then I want to see who owes them, again a bunch of names come up, and so on to level 5.

Maybe this is a well known scheme for which there is a well known simple answer in table design or MySQL circles. Could anybody suggest a MySQL query or perhaps an appropriate table design where I can use a simple query?

Example

```
ID      owes        owned to
1       Peter       John
2       John        George
3       Abdul       George
4       George      Anna
```

So I could design a wasteful table like this

```
ID    1        2         3       4      5
1     Anna     George    Abdul  
2     Anna     George    John    Peter
3     George   Abdul
4     George   John      Peter
5     John     Peter
```

But this would be very wasteful and bad bad design but it would be very easy to access the data along with the hierarchy and the owing chain.

Comment: You should try to avoid putting lists into columns. This is one of the first rules of database normalization.

Comment: By the 2nd and 3rd columns being a list of names, do you mean that there is a list per row in each of those (like an encoded array)?

Comment: Those would be not actual names but reference numbers for the names from a member database.

Comment: Lists should be put into a relationship table, and then you can use proper JOINs to follow all the links you're asking about in your question. You optimize by making sure you have indexes on the joining columns.

Comment: there is only one name per cell

Comment: How process intense is JOIN if I go to level 5 lets say. I am sure it will be less intense that doing separate SELECT queries anyway.

Comment: The way you've worded the description of your table is misleading - can you add a small example instead?

Comment: Should you not have a `people` table and then another than links two of those records together as someone that owes and the person owed?

Comment: @Sandor Instead of just asking the method try to elaborate the question with table structure and sample data with query what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems suitable:

```
people
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Marty  |
|  2 | Steven |
|  3 | John   |
+----+--------+
```

With the table building the relationships between people owed and owing:

```
loans
+-----------+-------------+
| lender_id | borrower_id |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |           2 |
|         1 |           3 |
|         2 |           1 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

You could get all the people owing a given lender with something as simple as:

```
SELECT people.id, people.name
FROM loans
INNER JOIN people ON people.id = loans.borrower_id
WHERE loans.lender_id = X
```

Where `X` is the id of the lender. Given the `lender_id` of `1` (Marty) for example would yield:

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  2 | Steven |
|  3 | John   |
+----+--------+
```

You can repeat this process for each of the resulting people until there are no results (no one being owed).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I will have to join the same table onto itself. Basically it comes down to the query and not some clever table design.

Comment: @Sandor If you did that, would you not have duplicates of the same person to accommodate the relationship with multiple lenders?

Comment: I want to be able to show on my site a structure where let say you would be on the top and all the people who owe you would be a level below you and all the people owing the would be another level down and so on to level 5. JOIN is the way to go. I just need to read through a couple of JOIN tutorials to see which one to use and how.

Comment: How would you cycle your code 5 times? Separate queries or you can write it into a single MySQL query?

Comment: @Sandor Separate queries. It wouldn't make much sense if the resultset had a dynamic amount of columns to accommodate varying amounts of owers.

Comment: Great, and I'm set. Thanks again for the help.